# Update a Set inside a nested Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I'm trying to update a Set in a nested Dictionary, problem is it adds a new Set instead of updating the current Set the 2nd time.

```
building = {}
building.update({'APT-14D':{}})
building['APT-14D'].setdefault('amenities', set()).add(('hot-water','gas-stove','non-smoke'))
building['APT-14D'].setdefault('amenities', set()).add(('hot-water','non-stove','non-smoke'))
```

I receive the following:

```
{'APT-14D': {'amenities': {('hot-water', 'non-stove', 'non-smoke'), ('hot-water', 'gas-stove', 'non-smoke')}}}
```

instead of:

```
{'APT-14D': {'amenities': {('hot-water', 'non-stove', 'non-smoke')}}}
```

How would I update the current value instead of making a new Set inside the nested dictionary?

P.S. The different values are `non-stove` and `gas-stove`

Comment: Yes, because you are adding *two different tuples* to you set.

Comment: If you want to replace the set use assignment `building['APT-14D']['amenities']={('hot-water', 'non-stove', 'non-smoke')}`. `setdefault` returns the value that is already stored, i.e. the set with the other element, and adds the new one to it.

Comment: Why do you have a set at all?

Comment: Is there a difference between a set that contains `'non-stove'` and a set that _doesn't_ contain `'gas-stove'` or `'any-other-kind-of-stove'`?  If that's a distinction you really need, then you'll have to screen out sets that contain both `'whatever-stove'` and `'non-stove'` (and all similar "impossible" combinations)... they _will_ show up one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't making a new set, you are *adding a different tuple to your set*. If you want to add each of the individual elements of your tuple to the set, use `.update`:

```
In [4]: building = {}
   ...: building.update({'APT-14D':{}})
   ...: building['APT-14D'].setdefault('amenities', set()).update(('hot-water','gas-stove','non-smoke'))
   ...: building['APT-14D'].setdefault('amenities', set()).update(('hot-water','non-stove','non-smoke'))
   ...:

In [5]: building
Out[5]:
{'APT-14D': {'amenities': {'gas-stove',
   'hot-water',
   'non-smoke',
   'non-stove'}}}
```

Rereading your question, I've notice that isn't even really what you want. It seems now that you don't even want a set, just a tuple, and just replace that tuple with whatever new value comes:

```
In [16]: building = {'APT-14D':{}}

In [17]: building['APT-14D']['amenities'] =  ('hot-water','gas-stove','non-smoke')

In [18]: building['APT-14D']['amenities'] =  ('hot-water','non-stove','non-smoke')

In [19]: building
Out[19]: {'APT-14D': {'amenities': ('hot-water', 'non-stove', 'non-smoke')}}
```

Comment: I was just trying the same thing, but this is an XY Problem -> what he asks for doesn't solve the problem. He wants `non-stove` to replace `gas-stove`

Comment: @TemporalWolf Oh jeez.